# Parse json response for highcharts

Tags: php, parsing, highcharts, json

I need you help guys. Im trying to parse a json response into something that highcharts can render into a column chart. I've searched and searched without any luck.

This is and example of how the json data should look like before rendering the chart:

```
[
[1,12],
[2,5],
[3,18],
[4,13],
[5,7],
[6,4],
[7,9],
[8,10],
[9,15],
[10,22]
]
```

And this is how my json response looks like:

```
{"col":["name","tot"],"grp":{"wkd":[["","0"],["id-1","0"],["id-2","0"],["id-3","0"],["id-4","0"],["id-5","0"],["id-6","0"],["id-7","0"]]},"Spec":{}}
```

The only information i need from the response is the id-1 through 7 and their values.

Im using curl to send a post request against an url with a token and secret.

This is the curl part of the code and the json_decode:

```
$ch = curl_init($signedUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json',
                                           'Accept-language: en-GB',
                                           'Content-type: application/json',                                                                                
                                           'Content-length: ' . strlen($data_string))); 

$json = curl_exec($ch);

print "RESPONSE BODY (as string (JSON)):<br/><br/>" . $json;
echo "<br><br>";

$data = json_decode($json, true);

curl_close($ch);
```

I have no idea how to parse the information after the json_decode. I've tried multiple foreach strings without any luck.
Could anyone help me with this?

Regards
Philip

Comment: If you are library agnostic, look at jquery's [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function

Comment: I think we need a bit more info about the make up of your page and chart. Are you doing this curl to get some data to load the chart on page render? Or are you making a call to this PHP script via AJAX call from the page after it is rendered? Could you zoom out a little on your app and give us more code to show how your chart is being created and how you are using your data? Right now this looks like a PHP question but the answer may depend on how it is being used.

Answer (score 1):

You want to break out the relevant part of the object, loop through, if the id is populated, grab it as data.  Then you'll need to re-json_encode it for use in the chart:

```
$json       = '{"col":["name","tot"],"grp":{"wkd":[["","0"],["id-1","0"],["id-2","0"],["id-3","0"],["id-4","0"],["id-5","0"],["id-6","0"],["id-7","0"]]},"Spec":{}}';
$decoded    = json_decode($json);
$values     = $decoded->grp->wkd;

$i = 0;
foreach($values as $k=>$arr) {
    $id = $arr[0];
    if(!empty($id)) {
        $data[$i][]     = $i;
        $data[$i][]     = $arr[1];
        $cats[$i]       = $id;
        $i++;
    }
}
$data = json_encode($data);
$cats = json_encode($cats);
```

This includes a section to build a categories array as well, if needed.  if not, simply omit.

The output of this routine is:

$data:

```
[[0,"0"],[1,"0"],[2,"0"],[3,"0"],[4,"0"],[5,"0"],[6,"0"]]
```

$cats:

```
["id-1","id-2","id-3","id-4","id-5","id-6","id-7"]
```